# V2 Google Map exception when in ViewPager

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a few working examples now that successfully display a V2 map.  But now I'm trying to display a V2 map on one of my pages in a ViewPager.  The problem is that while the map displays properly (the default display west of africa as I have no code yet) if I try to scroll it with my finger it blows and the LogCat listed below is generated.

On my other apps, I can scroll around and zoom in and out just fine but those maps are not in a viewpager.

Thanks, Gary

XML is ...

```
<fragment
android:id="@+id/map"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

LogCat is ...

> 08-15 17:25:49.480: E/AndroidRuntime(13358): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   08-15 17:25:49.480: E/AndroidRuntime(13358):
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.maps.MapView 08-15
>   17:25:49.480: E/AndroidRuntime(13358):    at
>   com.example.rtrtcontroller.CustomViewPager.canScroll(CustomViewPager.java:21)
>   08-15 17:25:49.480: E/AndroidRuntime(13358):  at
>   android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onInterceptTouchEvent(ViewPager.java:1837)
>   08-15 17:25:49.480: E/AndroidRuntime(13358):  at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:908) 08-15
>   17:25:49.480: E/AndroidRuntime(13358):    at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942) 08-15
>   17:25:49.480: E/AndroidRuntime(13358):    at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942) 08-15
>   17:25:49.480: E/AndroidRuntime(13358):    at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942) 08-15
>   17:25:49.480: E/AndroidRuntime(13358):    at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1867)
>   08-15 17:25:49.480: E/AndroidRuntime(13358):  at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1144)
>   08-15 17:25:49.480: E/AndroidRuntime(13358):  at
>   android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2096) 08-15
>   17:25:49.480: E/AndroidRuntime(13358):    at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1851)
>   08-15 17:25:49.480: E/AndroidRuntime(13358):  at
>   android.view.ViewRoot.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRoot.java:2207) 08-15
>   17:25:49.480: E/AndroidRuntime(13358):    at
>   android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1889) 08-15
>   17:25:49.480: E/AndroidRuntime(13358):    at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 08-15
>   17:25:49.480: E/AndroidRuntime(13358):    at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130) 08-15 17:25:49.480:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(13358):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683) 08-15
>   17:25:49.480: E/AndroidRuntime(13358):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 08-15
>   17:25:49.480: E/AndroidRuntime(13358):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507) 08-15 17:25:49.480:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(13358):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:875)
>   08-15 17:25:49.480: E/AndroidRuntime(13358):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:633) 08-15
>   17:25:49.480: E/AndroidRuntime(13358):    at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 08-15 17:25:49.480:
>   W/ActivityManager(201):   Force finishing activity
>   com.example.rtrtcontroller/.MainActivity 08-15 17:25:49.780:
>   E/CursorWindow(13174): need to grow: mSize = 1048576, size = 86016,
>   freeSpace() = 29218, numRows = 12 08-15 17:25:49.780:
>   E/CursorWindow(13174): not growing since there are already 12 row(s),
>   max size 1048576 08-15 17:25:49.780: E/Cursor(13174): Failed
>   allocating 86016 bytes for blob at 11,3 08-15 17:25:49.990:
>   W/ActivityManager(201): Activity pause timeout for
>   HistoryRecord{40d21768 com.example.rtrtcontroller/.MainActivity} 08-15
>   17:25:50.130: E/CursorWindow(13174): need to grow: mSize = 1048576,
>   size = 86016, freeSpace() = 29218, numRows = 12 08-15 17:25:50.130:
>   E/CursorWindow(13174): not growing since there are already 12 row(s),
>   max size 1048576 08-15 17:25:50.130: E/Cursor(13174): Failed
>   allocating 86016 bytes for blob at 11,3

Comment: Can you upload a small demo-app to Github, so we can run an try/debug it?

Comment: it says java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:..goto build path and set project dependences.

Comment: Kettu: What do you mean "set project dependences?" The Java build path is identical to the project that works (but does not have the map in a ViewPager).  Can you be more specific?